# How come .equals isn't working in this scenario? Even the Debugger is not making sense

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is my first post, so I'm sorry if I didn't do it correctly.
I'm trying to do this USACO problem but basically, my code is throwing an error every time for this particular test case for some reason on the .equals line

I know it's alot of code, but it's a really simple problem

Here's the code:

```java
public class gift1 {
    public static void main(String[] Args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("gift1.in"));

        int peeps = sc.nextInt();
        String[][] chart = new String[2][peeps];
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < peeps; i++) {
            chart[0][i] = sc.nextLine();
            chart[1][i] = "0";
        }
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String giver = sc.next();                               //we need to find giver
        int indexOfgiver = -1;                                      
        for(int i = 0; i < peeps; i++) {                            //finds indexOfgiver
            if(giver.equals(chart[0][i])) {
                indexOfgiver = i;                   
                break;
            }
        }
        int moneyTogive = sc.nextInt();
        chart[1][indexOfgiver] = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(chart[1][indexOfgiver]) - moneyTogive);
        int numReceivers = sc.nextInt();
        if(numReceivers == 0) {
            chart[1][indexOfgiver] = Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt(chart[1][indexOfgiver]) ); 
        }
        else {
            chart[1][indexOfgiver] = Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt(chart[1][indexOfgiver]) + (int) Math.floor(moneyTogive%numReceivers) ); 
        }
        String[] receivers = new String[numReceivers];          
        for(int i = 0; i < numReceivers; i++) {                     //list the receivers' names in an array 
            receivers[i] = sc.next();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < numReceivers; i++) {                     //give money to the receivers
            for(int j = 0; j < peeps; j++) {
                if(chart[0][j].equals(receivers[i])) {
                    chart[1][j] = Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt(chart[1][j]) + (int) Math.floor(moneyTogive/numReceivers));
                    }
                }
            }       

        }
        PrintWriter fW = new PrintWriter("gift1.out");
        for(int i = 0; i < peeps; i++)
            System.out.println(chart[0][i] + " " + chart[1][i]);    

    }
}
```

The error is occurring on line 31 (it's the ugly one that starts with chart[1][indexOfgiver]) and it's saying its an ArrayOutOfBoundsException, which means that the if statement line that is changing the value of variable `indexOfgiver` for some reason isn't working despite the file being correct.

Here's the file("gift1.in") I'm reading from with the scanner:

```
10 
mitnik
Poulsen
Tanner
Stallman
Ritchie
Baran
Spafford 
Farmer 
Venema
Linus
mitnik
300 3
Poulsen
Tanner
Baran
Poulsen
1000 1
Tanner
Spafford
2000 9
mitnik
Poulsen
Tanner
Stallman
Ritchie
Baran
Farmer
Venema
Linus
Tanner
```

Even the debugger is showing that during the first run of the while loop, ~giver~ is equal to "mitnik" and so is ~chart[0][0]~ , but the loop isn't setting ~indexOfgiver~ to ~i~. What is exactly happening?

Comment: Did you check if there is maybe a space character appended to the value (either in `giver` or in `chart[0][0]`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have space in names in input file, hence entry in chart array is **"Spafford "** instead of **"Spafford"** which you are trying to match.

Since it doesnt match index remains as -1 and causes IndexOutofBoundsException.